# Create an executable from a Python and PyGTk script under windows

Tags: python, windows, pygtk, msys2

I wrote in Linux a script in Python which uses PyGtk. I am trying to run it in Windows and create an executable.

The only working way I found to run python and PyGtk under Windows is using MSYS2. But, when I try to create an executable with Pyinstaller, the software fails.

For simplicity, in order to run some tests, I decided to try to make an executable for a much more simple script:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

After the command pyinstaller gtk_text.py

a window opens with the error "Unspecified fatal error encountered, aborting"

The following is the full output:

```
$ pyinstaller gtk_test.py
1468 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.12.0
1468 INFO: Python: 3.10.11
1562 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
1578 INFO: wrote C:/msys64/home/lsadmin/test_hello/gtk_test.spec
1578 INFO: UPX is not available.
1609 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:/msys64/home/lsadmin/test_hello']
3672 INFO: checking Analysis
3672 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
3672 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
3688 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
3766 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
10862 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
11175 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
16691 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
20895 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
21786 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
21801 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python.exe
22005 INFO: Analyzing C:/msys64/home/lsadmin/test_hello/gtk_test.py
22021 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.py'.
22114 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.py' from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
22552 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Gtk from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repositor
y.Gtk.py'.
22552 INFO: Processing module hooks...
22599 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.Gtk.py' from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
35021 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.GObject from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repos
itory.GObject.py'.
35037 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.GLib from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.reposito
ry.GLib.py'.
35068 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Gio from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repositor
y.Gio.py'.
35084 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Gdk from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repositor
y.Gdk.py'.
35084 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Atk from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.repositor
y.Atk.py'.
35084 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.Atk.py' from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
38913 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.Gdk.py' from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
42726 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.cairo from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.reposit
ory.cairo.py'.
42742 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.Pango from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.reposit
ory.Pango.py'.
42742 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi.repository.GdkPixbuf from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-gi.rep
ository.GdkPixbuf.py'.
42742 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gi.repository.GdkPixbuf.py' from 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...

GLib-WARNING (recursed) **: Failed to determine console output code page: The system could not find the environment option that was entered.. Falling back to UTF-8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/pyinstaller.exe/__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 194, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1030, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 952, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:/msys64/home/lsadmin/test_hello/gtk_test.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 604, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 329, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 447, in post_graph
    self._process_hook_func(analysis)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 469, in _process_hook_func
    self._hook_module.hook(hook_api)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-gi.repository.GdkPixbuf.py", line 128, in hook
    cachedata = _generate_loader_cache(gdk_pixbuf_query_loaders, libdir, loader_libs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-gi.repository.GdkPixbuf.py", line 83, in _generate_loader_cache
    cachedata = compat.exec_command_stdout(gdk_pixbuf_query_loaders, *loader_libs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 440, in exec_command_stdout
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(command_args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders.EXE', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-ani.dl
l', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-bmp.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-gif.dll', 'C:/
msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-icns.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-ico.dll', 'C:/msys64/
mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-jpeg.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64
/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-pnm.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-qtif.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/..
/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-tga.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk
-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-tiff.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-xbm.dll', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gdk-pixbuf
-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-xpm.dll')' returned non-zero exit status 3.
```

Any clue would be much appreciated.

Thank you, Luca

Comment: I know this isn't of much help but it works for me. What version of pyinstaller do you have? And python version? `pyinstaller -v` returns 5.7.0 for me.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late response, but I am busy with another project. Actually the fact that the script works on your machine is encouraging because it means that there is hope.
My version of pyinstaller is the same as yours. I guess I will try to reinstall everything in order to have a clean environment and run again some tests

Answer (score 0):

I found that the error was due to this line:

```
GLib-WARNING (recursed) **: Failed to determine console output code page: The system could not find the environment option that was entered.. Falling back to UTF-8
```

It can be solved (temporarily) with setting the correct character set with the command

```
chcp.com 65001
```

or in a permanent way, changing the "unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support".

This can be done from: Control Panel > Clock and Region > Region > Administrative tab > Change system locale button > enable Beta:Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support.